# When will be IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator be called?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have my users data back in my old app. I wanted to try IdentityServer4 for my auth with ASPNET Core Identity.

I've seen examples that they used Aspnet Core MVC with Auth for their login. They also implemented `IProfileService` and `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`.

Saw an example where he used Postman to connect to `http://localhost:5000/connect/token`, it triggered the `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator`

Now, when using the UI (referring to AspNet Core MVC Auth) for login, when will be the `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` be called? Or will it be ever called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` is the interface that denotes the contract for validating all resource owner password grant/flows.

Basically it will only be called when you do the password grant against the token endpoint. It will not be called upon in a normal UI based flow (like implicit flow for example). So if you try a password grant you will see it being used.

Comment: So, while using implicit flow if have to get users from db where I'll validate my users? as IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator will only be used for ResourceOwner flow ????

Comment: @ДвυΒдкдя You do all of this in your Controllers that serve up your login screen. So you have a controller that accepts a post from some login form and you do all of that validation there. Here is an example : https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI/blob/release/Quickstart/Account/AccountController.cs#L73-L95

Comment: Oh, I see got it Thank you.